# printing different sized arraylists on the same line

Tags: java, arraylist

Code:

```
r = getDouble();
double temp = 0.0;
double userInput = r;
for (i=0; temp<max; i++) {
temp += r;
    if (temp<1000) {
        Doublecol1.add(temp);
    } else if (temp<2000) { 
        Doublecol2.add(temp);
    }else if (temp<3000) {  
        Doublecol3.add(temp);
    }else if (temp<4000) {  
        Doublecol4.add(temp);
    }else if (temp<5000) {      
        Doublecol5.add(temp);
    }else if (temp<6000) {      
        Doublecol6.add(temp);
    }else if (temp<7000) {      
        Doublecol7.add(temp);
    }else if (temp<8000) {
        Doublecol8.add(temp);
    }else if (temp<9000) {  
        Doublecol9.add(temp);
    }else if (temp<10000) {     
        Doublecol10.add(temp);
    }
}


for (i=0;i<=Doublecol10.size();i++) {

System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n", Doublecol1.get(i), Doublecol2.get(i), Doublecol3.get(i), Doublecol4.get(i), Doublecol5.get(i), Doublecol6.get(i), Doublecol7.get(i), Doublecol8.get(i), Doublecol9.get(i), Doublecol10.get(i));
```

The arraylists are different lengths and I do not know how to accommodate for this. At the moment it gives and indexoutofbounds exception and all of the columns are the same length instead of printing all of the numbers in the arraylist
        }

Comment: [Didn't you already asked this question before today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505985/printing-arraylists-into-columns-in-java)

Comment: Man, I'd just put these lists in a list and index them by `temp/1000`.

Comment: I did ask but I didn't ask it in the right way

Comment: Then edit your first question instead of creating a new one. Or delete the old question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this might be what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int colCount = 10;
    final int maxRows = 5;

    final Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    final List<Double>[] doubles = new LinkedList[colCount];

    // initialize indices
    for (int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {
        doubles[i] = new LinkedList<>();

        // fill with random values
        for (int j = 0; j < rnd.nextInt(maxRows) + 1; j++) {
            // random value + number of column
            doubles[i].add(rnd.nextDouble() + (i + 1));
        }
    }

    // test output
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000000#");

    for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++) {
        for (List<Double> col : doubles) {
            result.append(String.format("%10s ", (col.size() > i) ? df.format(col.get(i)) : "          "));
        }
        result.append('\n');
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```